# Is observeOn requried for livedata postvalue?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, android-livedata

Is observe on part required in this case or posting value in livedata is itself enough for it to be processed correctly.

```
method()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(
     { liveData.postValue(it) },
     { Timber.e(it) }
  )
```

Answer (score 6):

`observeOn` will force all operations below it to run on a thread from the scheduler you pass as its parameter. In this case, you're forcing the subscription to work on the main thread. Read [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html) for more information.

`Livedata` has two ways of updating its value: you either do `livedata.setValue(newValue)` (`livedata.value = newValue` in Kotlin) or `livedata.postValue(newValue)`. The first option only works on the main thread. On the other hand, `postValue` is commonly used to set the value from a background thread (the background thread actually posts a task for the main thread to update the value).

Given all this, in this case, since you're using `postValue`, you don't need to force the subscription on the main thread. However, note that since `postValue` is not synchronous, calling it from the main thread does not guarantee immediate execution. For instance, in your subscriber, if you call a `livedata.postValue(newValue)` followed by `livedata.setValue(anotherValue)`, `setValue` will execute first. In other words, your `livedata`'s value will be set to `anotherValue`, and later overridden to `newValue`. If you want to keep the execution in the main thread, use `setValue`.

Answer (score 0):

`observeOn()` -> This method simply changes the thread of all operators further downstream (in the calls that come after).

`observeOn()` -> This only influences the thread that is used when the Observable is subscribed to and it will stay on it downstream

If the above case mentioned in question, if the calls after `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` needs to run on UI thread, basically `liveData.postValue(it)` does some changes on UI thread, then this line is needed.

If it's removed, the further calls will be run on thread spawned by `subscribeOn()` method.

Below link gives a nice explanation of subscribeOn() and observeOn() method:
https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a

Hope this helps.